# How to use form fields in template in django

Tags: python, django

i need your help, i'm trying to implement sign up functionality in django but i didn't know how to connect the template form to my view.

I'm using the following view :

```
def signup(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignupForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(request)
        subject = 'Activate your blog account.'
        message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
            'user':user, 'domain':current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        # user.email_user(subject, message)
        toemail = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(subject, message, to=[toemail])
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
else:
    form = SignupForm()
return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

And this is a part of the template i did :

```
<div class="centre">
  <h1>Register For An Account To Access Ultra Marker API</h1>
  <form class="form" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
     <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="First Name", value={{  }} >
     <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Last Name", value={{  }} >
     <input type="email" class="email" placeholder="Email", value={{  }} >
     <input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Username", value={{  }} >
     <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Password", value={{  }} />
     <input type="password"required autocomplete="off" placeholder="Confirm Password" value={{  }} />
     <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Register">
     <br/>
     <br/>
     <div style="text-align: right;padding-right: 10px">
     <a href="login/">Already registred ? Log in !</a>
  </div>
</form>
```

My forms.py:

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so first thing here is ALWAYS check if `if form.is_valid():` is true at some point. Easiest way to check that is `print test` and check the console when you hit submit button for the form.

in your views.py file you set up in the last line `return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})` with this you are passing the keyword `form` into the template and you can use it there.

```
<form method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' >
{% csrf_token %}
{{form}}
<button type="submit" class="btn ban-default fa fa-cloud-upload">
</form>
```

in your template you can use the `form` keyword like this. now you form should show up and then can be rendered in the form validation.

> EDIT

Since its more about how to style a form:
In my templates I use [Widget Tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks)

```
<form method='POST' action="/" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.first_name |add_class:"customCSS1 customCSS2" }}
 {{ form.second_name |add_class:"customCSS3 customCSS4" }}
</form>
{{ form.media.js }}
```

with this plugin you can style the form as you wish. All Css classes work

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need the html tag <input... so that i can use my css stylesheet

Comment: yeah you can do that in the next step. its no problem to achieve that but first you backend needs to work before you care about how things look like

Comment: I already tested with this template and it worked : {% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {% for field in form %}
      <p>
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% if field.help_text %}
          <small style="display: none">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
        {% endif %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
      </p>
      {% endfor %}

    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}

Comment: I tried this tutoriel but i want to customize it to use my own template and css : https://farhadurfahim.github.io/post/django-registration-with-confirmation-email/

Comment: so if you had a working form why do you change it to that and then post a question like this? why won't you ask directly on how to style a form properly with custom CSS?

Comment: @c.ceti please have look at the edited answer. This works. Add all your fields like that.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i'll try it. Why is there 2 names for class

Comment: @c.ceti in case you want to add more than one css class.